# Spring REST deserialize JSON array as a Set<?>

Tags: java, spring, jackson, spring-data-rest

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2, Spring Data REST, Spring HATEOAS.
I'm facing a strange problem. I've a RestController accepting this object:

```
@Data
public class DocumentJSON {

    @Valid
    private Document document;

    private List<DocumentRow> rows = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<DocumentVat> vats = new ArrayList<>();

    private Set<DocumentPayment> payments = new HashSet<>();

    private boolean updateContactDetail = false;

}
```

and `DocumentPayment` is:

```
    @Data
    @EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true, onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Builder
    @ToString(callSuper = true)
    public class DocumentPayment extends AbstractEntity {

        @ToString.Exclude
        @JsonDeserialize(using = DocumentUriDeserializer.class)
        @NotNull
        @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        private Document document;

        @NotNull
        @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DATE")
        private Instant date;

        //Optional contact (the receipt has not a contact)
        @ToString.Exclude
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        private Contact contact;

        @NotBlank
        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String description;

        @ToString.Exclude
        @JsonDeserialize(using = FinancialAccountUriDeserializer.class)
        @NotNull(message = "{documentpayment.financialaccount.missing}")
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        private FinancialAccount financialAccount;

        @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
        @NotNull
        @Column(nullable = false, length = 30)
        private PaymentType paymentType;

        //The amount, negative for payment to suppliers
        @NotNull
        @ColumnDefault("0.00")
        @Column(nullable = false, scale = 2, columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(12,2)")
        private BigDecimal amount = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        //The amount paid
        @NotNull
        @ColumnDefault("0.00")
        @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(12,2)")
        private BigDecimal paid = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.READ_ONLY)
        @Generated(value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS)
        @Column(columnDefinition = "DECIMAL(12,2) AS (amount-paid) VIRTUAL NOT NULL")
        private BigDecimal due;

        @ToString.Exclude
        @JsonDeserialize(using = StoreUriDeserializer.class)
        //@NotNull(message = "{documentpayment.store.missing}")
        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
        @JoinColumn(name = "store_id", updatable = false)
        private Store store;    
    }
```

The client is sending a Json like this:

```
{
  "document": {
    "date": "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z",
    "type": "SALES_RECEIPT",
    "store": "http://95.255.117.252:8082/api/v1/stores/1",
    "rounding": 0,
    "amount": 19.23,
    "taxAmount": 0.77,
    "totalAmount": 20
  },
  "rows": [
    {
      "index": 1,
      "productType": "FRAME",
      "qty": 1,
      "rowGroup": null,
      "unitPrice": 9.615,
      "percentageDiscount": 0,
      "purchaseUnitPrice": null,
      "amount": 9.615,
      "description": "Prodotto1",
      "taxRate": "http://95.255.117.252:8082/api/v1/taxRates/2",
      "note": false
    },
    {
      "index": 1,
      "productType": "OPHTHALMIC_LENS",
      "qty": 1,
      "rowGroup": null,
      "unitPrice": 9.615,
      "percentageDiscount": 0,
      "purchaseUnitPrice": null,
      "amount": 9.615,
      "description": "Lente",
      "taxRate": "http://95.255.117.252:8082/api/v1/taxRates/2",
      "note": false
    }
  ],
  "payments": [
    {
      "date": "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z",
      "financialAccount": "http://95.255.117.252:8082/api/v1/financialAccounts/1",
      "paymentType": "CASH",
      "amount": "10"
    },
    {
      "date": "2019-10-18T00:00:00.000Z",
      "financialAccount": "http://95.255.117.252:8082/api/v1/financialAccounts/3",
      "paymentType": "CREDIT_CARD",
      "amount": "10"
    }
  ],
  "updateContactDetail": false
}
```

but when I debug in the first line of the REST controller I see only 1 payment.

Changing the property payments in `DocumentJSON` from `Set<DocumentPayment>` to `List<DocumentPayment>`, I get 2 payments as expected with the same JSON.

Am I missing something or Spring/Jackson are not able to deserialize in the right way a Set<>?

Comment: Sets has no duplicates. I guess that `equals()` returns the same value.

Comment: The reason is that sets do not contain duplicate elements, whereas list can.Both the objects in payments might be duplicate.

Comment: You have `onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true`. Did you use `@EqualsAndHashCode.Include`?

Comment: @PeterMmm you are right. I did use EqualsAndHashCode.Include but on fields that the client doesn't set. So the server has no way to understand that that payments are different. Thanks to pointed me in the right direction!